# What's a good strategy to move crosshairs in a plot interactively?

Tags: r, plot, d3.js, interactive, shiny

I'm in the early stages of planning a function that needs to interactively move crosshairs within a plot.  Here are some base graphics calls that will do this in a very clunky way:

```
set.seed(9)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
plot(df)

abline(v = 0.5, h = 1.2, col = "red") # 'original' crosshairs
loc <- locator() # click location in plot, then ESC
abline(v = 0.5, h = 1.2, col = "transparent") # clear 'original' crosshairs
abline(h = loc$x[1], v = loc$y[2], col = "green") # crosshairs at new position
```

What I need is the ability to control the crosshair positions in a precise way, and also return their location.  Clicking in the above example does not really give sufficiently fine control. I'd like to be able to use the left-right-up-down arrows on the keyboard to step around.  But I don't think R 'listens' to the l-r-u-d keys in this manner (i.e. when in the graphics window).  If I'm wrong, please correct me.  Another way I can imagine this working is that the crosshairs follow the cursor until one clicks or something similar.

So I'm looking for a strategy to do this, with the data in R.  The graphics pkg doesn't matter (base, ggplot2, lattice) and the data and interactive feature could be in some other language, maybe displayed in a web page if needed.  I'm thinking one of the newer approaches to interactive graphics like `d3` or `shiny`.  I've looked at these a little but really need someone who does this sort of stuff regularly to point me in the right direction.

I'll also need the ability to zoom and annotate but I can solve these problems within whatever framework is ultimately chosen.  But I mention this so those providing an answer know there are other tasks in addition to the one I specifically mention.  So maybe one particular approach will strike someone as 'the way to go'.  Finally, the real data set will be large so speed is a concern.

Comment: This is quite a vague question. It seems to me that any answers would be primarily opinion-based. It certainly sounds to me like D3 would be a good fit, but if you're starting out in R it may not be the best choice.

Comment: Well, I may have worded it less than ideally.  I am wondering whether any of the options I mentioned or any others unknown to me have the capabilities I seek, which isn't really opinion.  I'm hoping someone here has done something similar.

Comment: Acinonyx is fast and has some interactive features. It lacks documentation and finishing touches, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
set.seed(9)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
plot(df)

abline(v = 0.5, h = 1.2, col = "red") # 'original' crosshairs
while (T) {
  loc <- locator(1) # click location in plot, then ESC
  plot(df) # clear 'original' crosshairs
  abline(h = loc$y, v = loc$x, col = "green") # crosshairs at new position
}
```

If you need more power, Shiny is a fine choice (in my biased opinion), and d3 is probably overkill unless you are already very skilled at HTML, JavaScript, and SVG.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different functions in the TeachingDemos package that use interactive positioning with the mouse in a graphics window.  The TkIdentify function uses a Tk window and shows live dragging, the dynIdentify function works similarly but does not require Tk (it uses `getGraphicsEvent`, so you need a system that supports that, I know Windows does).  The `HWidentify` and `HTKidentify` functions also follow the mouse.

The `playSudoku` function in the sudoku package also reads the current mouse pointer position in a graph and also reads keypresses from the keyboard (has both options for a Tk window or using `getGrahpicsEvent`).

These could also be adapted to use the manipulate package for RStudio (I have plans along that line for the TeachingDemos).  I don't know shiny enough yet to know how easy it would be to do this in shiny.

I would suggest looking at the above mentioned functions to see if the functionality is similar to what you want, and if so, then look at the code and see how you can adapt it to needs.